# Regular expression to modify the line following a line that begins with a key phrase?

Tags: regex

I have a huge file that has some lines that need to have a line of dashes underneath them followed by an empty line.

All of these lines start with the same particular word pattern (**`"Dollars required for"`**) but every other word on the line is different from one line to the next.

For example, the document looks like this at the moment:

```
Dollars required for: "International Exchange"
Some other text on the next line
...
Dollars required for: "Trade Operations"
(blank line)
Some other text on the next line
```

But it needs to look like this:

```
Dollars required for: "International Exchange"
---------------------------------------------- (inserted line of dashes)
                                               (inserted blank line)
Some other text on the next line
...
Dollars required for: "Trade Operations"
---------------------------------------------- (inserted line of dashes)
                                               (inserted blank line)
(blank line)
Some other text on the next line
```

Is there a Regular Expression I could use in the Find/Replace feature of my text editor (Jedit) to perform this modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find:

```
Dollars required for: (.*)$
```

Replace with:

```
Dollars required for: $1\n----------------------------------------------\n
```

(This is assuming the find/replace supports escapes for newlines, et cetera.)

Comment: Cool! Thanks! Would that only target lines that *begin* with "Dollars required for" (in other words, the letter 'D' of the word 'Dollar' is the very first character on the line)?

Comment: If you need to ensure that it's only lines which begin with that, add a `^` to the beginning of the match (`^` is the "start of line" anchor).

Answer (score 1):

Search for:

```
 ^(Dollars required for: .*)$
```

Replace with:

```
 $1\n----------------------------------------------\n\n
```

Jedit can do it IRC.

Comment: Having `\n\n` on the end would insert two blank lines, not one.

Comment: According to the question, that's the desired output.

Comment: No - there's already an existing blank line in the spot where the desired output shows two. You shouldn't be *adding* two, only one (for a sum total of twp).

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm misinterpreting but his desired output shows as: $1 -> line of dashes -> inserted blank line -> (Some other text on the next line) - at least in the first "section". And if I add only one then JEdit should not add the inserted blank line after the dash only line. 

Or am I wrong?